# How to config ssl for SonarQube in azure?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have installed sonarqube-5.6.1 in a azure windows server 2012. The site sonar (http) work well. But i don't find how can i config ssl (https) for my site.
Can you tell me how can i do it please ?
Thank very much.

Comment: You cannot do that. They removed that option in the latest release. See the [docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE55/Securing+the+Server+Behind+a+Proxy) and this [reverse proxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) article.

Comment: Thank you very much. It work for me now.